# CWD unicode support

Tags: perl, unicode, path, operating-system, cwd

Is the [CWD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cwd) module regarding Unicode not up to date or is abs_path supposed only to be used when writing to the OS?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use File::Spec::Functions qw(rel2abs);

chdir '/tmp';

my $file = "Hello \x{263a}";

open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
say $fh 'test';
close $fh;

say abs_path $file;
say rel2abs $file;
```

output:

```
# /tmp/Hello âº
# /tmp/Hello ☺
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cwd module uses `char *` types internally and so does not handle encoding at all. Generally, filesystems do not care what characters or encoding you use for your filenames, as long as you escape any special characters (e.g. '/')

If you want to tell Perl the file path is in UTF-8, you can encode it:

```
use Encode qw(decode_utf8);

...
say decode_utf8(abs_path $file);
```

Comment: @sid_com You always want to pass the encoding/decoding functions an extra argument, usually  `1`, so that you can detect encoding errors. Here that would be `decode_utf8(abs_path($file), 1)`. There are other, fancier values you can import from the `Encode` module to pass in there; the 1 there is equivalent to `FB_CROAK`, which will raise an exception on error instead of hiding it from you.

Comment: Should be `decode_utf8(abs_path encode_utf8($file));`, and that's assuming your file names use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Perl leaves it to you to decode paths it returns and encode paths you provide. (YUCK!)

Comment: I agree that this is suboptimal and messy, but do you have a better idea? How in the world could this be done automatically, correctly, and portably?

Comment: @tchrist, I don't buy that file names can't be read or displayed. Therefore, it can be done. It could be *hard* to do, which is all the more reason to do the work once in the language rather than having each programmer come up with a inevitably broken solution.

Comment: Doesn’t it depend not only on the operating system, but on each mounted file system? If it’s in an 8-bit encoding, who’s to say how that should be treated? A user’s locale settings could even change that. I really don’t know how it could be done. It seems unsafe to automatically encode/decode UTF-8, because that’s not always what it is.

Comment: @tchrist, So your argument is: Since some systems are so broken that one cannot determine the encoding of a file name, it's better to let the user handle it. I don't see how the conclusion follows from the premise. What makes you think the user is better at handling it?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland. Assumes utf-8 system :(